# h1 won't center align

Tags: html, css

I have set h1 "Our Brands" to be center aligned but it appears slightly right off center. why is this occuring?

https://codepen.io/fjenpen/pen/pROPov

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/repairing-lawn-   mower-engine-picture-id500782948");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    text decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Because the `ul` ancestor element still has a default padding-left from the browser stylesheet - so set that to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNqgYJ). The key are the following lines:

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0
}
```

The "Our Brands" text is wrapped inside `ul#menu` which automatically gets some padding. You need to clear this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul` has default `padding-left`. Update this to `padding-left: 0;` and the text will be at center.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from `ul` tag:

```
 <ul id="menu" style="list-style-type: none;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
```